# How to remove duplicate in list based on two custom objects

Tags: java, sorting, collections, duplicates

I have `ProductDetail` class which contains two variables `productName` and `productVersion`. I need to replace duplicate items in the list according to the latest `productVersion`.

Example:

```
class ProductDetails {
   string productName;
   string productVersion;
}
new ProductDetails("ios", "9.1.0")
new ProductDetails("android", "6.0.1")
new ProductDetails("android", "5.1.1")
new ProductDetails("ios", "10.0.0")
```

Result:
android 6.0.1
ios 10.0.0

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) Convert product version to a long.  2) Sort by productName, productVersionLong descending.  3) Keep first row of each productName.  4)  Profit!!

Comment: This does not need sorting at all. Just use a Map. The most tricky bit will be properly comparing the version numbers.

Comment: thank you for your input guys. I do not want to sort a list. I will try your approach Gilbert Le Blanc

Comment: @RIACreate will this help, i hope this is the right answer you are looking for [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37813338/how-to-remove-duplicate-in-list-based-on-two-custom-objects/37817664#37817664)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work out for you:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class ProductDetails {

private String productName;
private String productVersion;
private List<ProductDetails> productData = null;

public ProductDetails(String productName,String productVersion){
    this.productName = productName;
    this.productVersion = productVersion;
    if(productData == null) {
        productData = new ArrayList<ProductDetails>();
        adNewProduct(this);
    }
}

private void  adNewProduct(ProductDetails p){
    String[] s1 = p.productVersion.split(Pattern.quote("."));
    for (ProductDetails dpp: productData) {
        if (dpp.productName.equals(p.productName)) {
            int index = productData.indexOf(dpp);
            String[] s2 = dpp.productVersion.split(Pattern.quote("."));
            for(int i = 0; i < s1.length; i++) {
                int v1 = Integer.valueOf(s1[i]);
                int v2 = Integer.valueOf(s2[i]);

                if (v1 > v2) {
                    productData.set(index,p);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    productData.add(p);
}


@Override  // you can modify it to how you want
public String toString(){
   
    String s = "";

    for (ProductDetails p: productData){
        s += "ProductName: " + p.productName + " ProductVersion: " + p.productVersion + "\n";
    }
    return s;
}


//the main method
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ProductDetails k = new ProductDetails("ios", "9.1.1");
    k.adNewProduct(new ProductDetails("android", "5.1.1"));
    k.adNewProduct(new ProductDetails("android", "6.0.1"));
    k.adNewProduct(new ProductDetails("ios", "10.0.0"));

    System.out.println(k);

    }

}
```

Output:

> ProductName: ios ProductVersion: 10.0.0
>
> ProductName: android ProductVersion: 6.0.1

Comment: @tobias_k doesn't really make any difference. was doing something else in this other class.. i think i have to edit well.

Answer (score 2):

You can put all those objects into a `Map<String, ProductDetails>` and keep the one with the latest version.

```
List<ProductDetails> details = Arrays.asList(
        new ProductDetails("ios", "9.1.0"),
        new ProductDetails("android", "6.0.1"),
        new ProductDetails("android", "5.1.1"),
        new ProductDetails("ios", "10.0.0"));

// get part of version string
Function<Integer, Function<ProductDetails, Integer>> version = 
        n -> (pd -> Integer.valueOf(pd.getProductVersion().split("\\.")[n]));
// chain to comparator
Comparator<ProductDetails> versionComp = Comparator.comparing(version.apply(0))
        .thenComparing(version.apply(1)).thenComparing(version.apply(2));

Map<String, ProductDetails> latest = new HashMap<>();
for (ProductDetails pd : details) {
    String name = pd.getProductName();
    if (! latest.containsKey(name) || versionComp.compare(latest.get(name), pd) < 0) {
        latest.put(name, pd);
    }
}
```

Afterwards, `latest` is:

```
{android=Sandbox.ProductDetails(productName=android, productVersion=6.0.1), 
 ios=Sandbox.ProductDetails(productName=ios, productVersion=10.0.0)}
```

Or, you can use `Collectors.groupingBy` and then use the same `Comparator`:

```
details.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ProductDetails::getProductName))
        .values().stream().map(list -> Collections.max(list, versionComp))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```